# Qual a diferença entre display:inline-block e float:left

Tags: css, css3

Ao testar com alinhamento de `div`, ambas tem a mesma finalidade

Mas qual seria a sua diferença?

Comment: Você poderia postar o código onde foi testado?

Comment: Em determinados contextos podem ter o mesmo resultado, mas certamente não tem a mesma finalidade.

Answer (score 4):

`inline-block` é a junção dos comportamentos `inline` (ex.:ocupar apenas o espaço do conteúdo, não quebrar linha) e `block` (ex.: dimensões configuráveis) em um único elemento HTML

`float` faz com que o elemento flutue na direção especificada acima dos outros elementos HTML.

Eles podem ser parecidos porque o float adiciona algumas características que o `inline-block`também possui, mas não todas.

Answer (score 2):

Em algumas situações um pode substituir o outro, mas não necessariamente fazem a mesma coisa. De uma olhada nesse artigo http://www.tutorialwebdesign.com.br/display-vs-float/ que tem explicação com exemplos.

Comment: Ótimo artigo de referência! Eu sempre usei/uso o `float`, mas achei interessante as comparações... talvez comece a testar o `inline-block` também.

Answer (score 1):

[Propriedade Float](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

[Propriedade Display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Float: left;

> The element floats to the left

Display:inline-block

> Displays an element as an inline-level block container. The inside of this block is formatted as block-level box, and the element itself is formatted as an inline-level box

Basicamente, o float left só joga as coisas para a esquerda, já o inline-block seta que eles devem adquirir formato de linha enquanto houver espaço e quando o espaço acabar ele, em forma de bloco, quebra para a próxima linha.

Nos links do inicio tem exemplos.