# Elementos do JavaScript quebrando linha

Tags: javascript, html

Criei um HTML simples só pra testar o comportamento do JavaScript no documento HTML, porém o elemento JavaScript pula uma nova linha quando na verdade eu quero que ele fique na mesma linha do texto.

```js
var casa = {
  quartos: 3,
  cores: ['branca', 'cinza'],
  janelas: true,
};
//Adiciona uma propriedade ao objeto
casa.cores[2] = 'verde';

//Modifica a mensagem true por uma outra
if (casa.janelas = true) {
  casa.janelas = 'tem janelas';
}

//Pega a quantidade de quartos da casa
var numQuartos = document.getElementById('quartosNumero');
numQuartos.textContent = casa.quartos;

//Pega as cores existentes na casa
var numCores = document.getElementById('coresCasa');
numCores.textContent = casa.cores;

//Exibe se tem janelas
var bolJanela = document.getElementById('temJanela');
bolJanela.textContent = casa.janelas;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <title>Começando com javascript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Esta é a casa</h1>
  <p>Quantidade de quartos:
    <div id="quartosNumero"></div>
  </p>
  <p>Cores presentes:
    <div id="coresCasa"></div>
  </p>
  <p>Extra:
    <div id="temJanela"></div>
  </p>
  <script src="ex1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use `span` em vez de `div`

Comment: Seu problema não tem a ver com JavaScript, mas com HTML. Além do que você não pode colocar uma div dentro de um parágrafo `<p>`.

Answer (score 5):

Como mencionado nos comentários seu problema é sobre HTML e não está relacionado a JavaScript, a solução se dá pela substituição do elemento [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div), dentro dos parágrafos [`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p), por um elemento [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) que é um container genérico **em linha** para conteúdo fraseado.

Mas o por que disso?

Na documentação sobre o [Modelo de Conteúdo HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html) especifica o elemento `<p>` como sendo um [elemento fraseado](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content):

> 3.2.5.2.5 Conteúdo do fraseado
>
> O conteúdo fraseado é o texto do documento, bem como os elementos que marcam esse texto a nível
> intra-parágrafo. Uma sequencia de conteúdo fraseado que forma um bloco de texto é um
> parágrafo.
>
> A maioria dos elementos que são categorizados como conteúdo de frases
> só podem conter apenas elementos que são categorizados como conteúdo
> de frases, e não qualquer conteúdo de fluxo.

Já o elemento `<div>` está classificado como um [elemento de fluxo](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content) o que o impede de ser utilizado dentro do elemento `<p>` pois como mostrado acima *elementos que são categorizados como conteúdo de frases não podem conter um conteúdo de fluxo qualquer, apenas conteúdo de texto*.

```js
var casa = {
  quartos: 3,
  cores: ['branca', 'cinza'],
  janelas: true,
};
//Adiciona uma propriedade ao objeto
casa.cores[2] = 'verde';

//Modifica a mensagem true por uma outra
if (casa.janelas = true) {
  casa.janelas = 'tem janelas';
}

//Pega a quantidade de quartos da casa
var numQuartos = document.getElementById('quartosNumero');
numQuartos.textContent = casa.quartos;

//Pega as cores existentes na casa
var numCores = document.getElementById('coresCasa');
numCores.textContent = casa.cores;

//Exibe se tem janelas
var bolJanela = document.getElementById('temJanela');
bolJanela.textContent = casa.janelas;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <title>Começando com javascript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Esta é a casa</h1>
  <p >Quantidade de quartos:
    <span id="quartosNumero"></span>
  </p>
  <p>Cores presentes:
    <span id="coresCasa"></span>
  </p>
  <p>Extra:
    <span id="temJanela"></span>
  </p>
  <!--script src="ex1.js"></script-->
</body>

</html>
```

Outra abordagem, respeitando as normas citadas acima, seria separar os elementos de fluxo dos elementos fraseados e aplica um estilo aos elementos `<p>` e `<div>` modificando a propriedade [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display) que irá especificar o tipo de caixa de renderização desses elementos.

No caso será utilizado a o `display: inline-block` que segundo essa [resposta de Renato Dinhani](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66393/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-displayinline-block-e-floatleft) e essa [resposta de splattne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block):

> `inline-block` é a junção dos comportamentos `inline` (ex.:ocupar
> apenas o espaço do conteúdo, não quebrar linha) e `block` (ex.:
> dimensões configuráveis) em um único elemento HTML. Elementos com
> `display:inline-block`são como elementos `display:inline`, mas eles
> podem ter uma largura e uma altura . Isso significa que você pode usar
> um elemento de bloco embutido como um bloco enquanto o flui dentro de
> texto ou outros elementos.

- No caso tanto as propriedades [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/margin), [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/padding), [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/height) e [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/width) não serão introduzidas na folha de estilo e usarão o valor default de cada navegador pois não são o foco.

```js
var casa = {
  quartos: 3,
  cores: ['branca', 'cinza'],
  janelas: true,
};
//Adiciona uma propriedade ao objeto
casa.cores[2] = 'verde';

//Modifica a mensagem true por uma outra
if (casa.janelas = true) {
  casa.janelas = 'tem janelas';
}

//Pega a quantidade de quartos da casa
var numQuartos = document.getElementById('quartosNumero');
numQuartos.textContent = casa.quartos;

//Pega as cores existentes na casa
var numCores = document.getElementById('coresCasa');
numCores.textContent = casa.cores;

//Exibe se tem janelas
var bolJanela = document.getElementById('temJanela');
bolJanela.textContent = casa.janelas;
```

```css
p,
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <title>Começando com javascript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Esta é a casa</h1>
  <p>Quantidade de quartos:</p> <!-- Aqui há uma clara distinção entre elementos de fluxo e fraseados -->
  <div id="quartosNumero"></div>
  <br>   <!-- Uma quebra de linha é introduzida para fazer a separação-->
  <p>Cores presentes:</p>
  <div id="coresCasa"></div>
  <br>
  <p>Extra:</p>
  <div id="temJanela"></div>
  <br>
  <!--script src="ex1.js"></script-->
</body>

</html>
```